# Autoscaling program Bosh/Concourse

Tags: concourse, cf-bosh, bosh-deployer, concourse-git-resource

I am developing a autoscaling program for Bosh running Concourse, what is the language/process to writing the program and then implementing it in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Any language you want! That's the beauty of Concourse. As long as you can create a `runC`-compatible image (like a Docker image) that can run your program, you can use it in Concourse. I've personally written tasks in bash, python, ruby, and go.